# Is it possible to constrain `Self` to a generic parameter?

Tags: swift

I'm having some issues with a delegate protocol that has associated types. Currently, my implementation looks like this:

```swift
protocol Delegate: AnyObject {
    associatedtype Foo

    func doSomething(with bar: Bar<Self>) -> Foo
}

class Bar<T: Delegate> {
    weak var delegate: T?

    func makeFoo() -> T.Foo? {
        return delegate?.doSomething(with: self)
    }
}
```

While this works, the constraint of `Bar<Self>` prevents the delegate from being a non-`final` class. I want to say something like this:

```swift
protocol Delegate: AnyObject {
    associatedtype Foo

    func doSomething<T: Delegate>(with bar: Bar<T>) -> Foo
    where Self: T
}
```

However, *even though `T` is constrained to `AnyObject`*, it gives me the error:

> `Type 'Self' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'T'`

Is there any type-safe way to allow the delegate to belong to a non-`final` class?

Comment: What about `func doSomething<T>(with bar: Bar<T>) -> Foo where T: Delegate, T.Foo == Self.Foo` ?

Comment: Wow, that works! Thank you; I would appreciate it if you add this as an answer instead of just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it using:

```
func doSomething<T: Delegate>(with bar: Bar<T>) -> Foo where T.Foo == Foo
```

It seems using `T: Self` does not work here and you have to add the condition for equal associated types.

Comment: Self is redundant `T.Foo == Foo`